# How to check if its IDP initiated logon request

Tags: c#, identityserver4, okta, idp

How to check if its IDP initiated logon request
I am using Okta as IDP and Identityserver4 as SP. SP initiated SSO is working fine but when I do IDP initiated login by clicking on app from okta dashboard, the fisrt time i do nee dto click on Sign in button and only then subsequently get to landing page of my app.

I need to do External/callback to skip login page but how do i know the request is coming from Okta dashboard. please advise

Comment: With OpenID Connect, it is always the client application that initiates the login flow, not IdentityServer or Okta.

Comment: Is it OIDC or SAML integration? Based on your terminology it seems like SAML, but previous comment is about OIDC. It would be nice to clarify

Comment: Its SAML and front end angular is using oidc package however. they say an endpoint can be configured in okta but In could not find where, still waiting for okta support response. however I found a workaround for now to trigger endpoint as soon as front end redirects to identity server after clicking on okta dashboard myapp icon. thank you.